# Trouble understanding VBA code .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))

Tags: excel, vba

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
```

Can someone explain what this code means?
I'm pretty new to VBA and have trouble understanding the syntax of certain code logic.

Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, in what case would there be a dot operator (.) used in front of the Range object.
I thought that Range is a range-type object created and that a dot operator indicates a function of some sort? (Coming from a java background)

Comment: Look at [With..End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement).  Somewhere before your code will be a something like `With Worksheets("Sheet1")`.  The dot notation means it's referring to what was used in the `With` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That snippet is usually used in combination with a `with sheet(...)` to get the last populated row.

Example:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    LR = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)).Count
End With
```

Here LR will be the last row in column A that has a value.

The row of code does the following:
Create a range from A1 (cells(1,1)) to A & (last filled row) by setting the "selector" at the last row and doing a CTRL + UP-arrow (kind of).
Then it returns the count of this range to LR.

You can get the same result using this slightly shorter syntax:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Where it instead of creating a range, just do the CTRL + UP-arrow from last row in column A, and return the row number.

The real beauty of the shorter syntax is that you can easily change it to get the last value:

```
With ws
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value   ' .row is changed to .value
End With
```

Comment: Ohh, wow thanks for the explaination! I think I got it:)

Comment: It will be helpful to others if you accept the answer so that others can see that there is an answer that is "correct" to your question.